# OpenLDAP complains that the fields are not indexed

Tags: linux, ldap, search-indexing, openldap

I am using OpenLDAP (slapd) v2.4.47 on Debian.
It complains in the following manner in the logfile (`/var/log/debug`)

```
slapd[1142]: conn=1508 op=4 SRCH base="cn=persons,cn=internal" scope=2 deref=0 filter="(&(objectClass=mozillaAbPersonAlpha)(|(cn=john*)(mail=john*)(sn=john*)))"
slapd[1142]: <= mdb_substring_candidates: (cn) not indexed                                                       
slapd[1142]: <= mdb_substring_candidates: (mail) not indexed                                                     
slapd[1142]: <= mdb_substring_candidates: (sn) not indexed
```

The corresponding database (`/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}mdb.ldif`) configuration is:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
olcDbIndex: cn,sn,mail,uid,sambaSID eq
olcDbIndex: uidNumber,gidNumber eq
olcDbIndex: member,memberUid eq
olcDbIndex: sambaDomainName eq
...
```

also when I try to add index on the "problematic" attribute (e.g. `cn`), it fails:

```
# ldapmodify -H ldapi:// -Y EXTERNAL <<EOM
dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcDbIndex
olcDbIndex: cn eq
EOM
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config"
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
        additional info: duplicate index definition for attr "cn"
```

This way I have tried all of `cn`, `mail`, `sn` with the same error, so it seems that the index is active on these attributes.

Why then OpenLDAP complains about missing indexes?

P.S. I have only one OpenLDAP running, so no way I could mess up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its complaining you need SUBstring indexes, not just equality indexes. You can add them with the "sub" keyword. For example:

```
olcDbIndex: cn,mail,sn sub,eq
```